# Application.ScreenUpdating in Subroutine called within Subroutine

Tags: vba, excel

This isn't really a code specific question, but more something to satisfy curiousity (and avoid future issues), so I thought SO would be a fitting place to ask it.

The basis of my question is this:  how does VBA treat `Application.ScreenUpdating` and other such calls from a subroutine that is called within a subroutine?

To illustrate with an example, I have a method `BackupData` that just very quickly takes the data from the activesheet and copies it to a hidden sheet with the same name and "Backup" appended (I use this to provide my users with an "Undo" macro since you can't use regular methods to undo the actions of a subroutine).  In `BackupData`, I toggle `ScreenUpdating` to False and True just so that the action is completely hidden from the end user. The problem in question arises from the fact that I give the user free access to running the macro, but also choose to call it from other macros which also toggle the `ScreenUpdating` property.

So, if `BackupData` is called from within a macro *after* that macro has toggled the `ScreenUpdating` property to False, will the `BackupData` call to set the property to True override the "outer" routine's call, thus leaving the rest of that macro to run with screen updating on?

Now, obviously, I know there are plenty of easy solutions to this issue.  I could store a boolean in `BackupData` that checks if `ScreenUpdating` is already false and then not return it to true if that is the case, or I can simply always repeat the `ScreenUpdating = False` call after running `BackupData`, or I could even write an identical sub to `BackupData` that doesn't toggle the value that I run from inside these other macros, but the point of this question isn't finding that solution.

I guess this is more of a question of how VBA works with nested subroutine calls, but I'm hoping someone here might be able to satisfy my curiousity with a definitive answer as to whether VBA will handle the issue for me or if I need to use one of the afformentioned workarounds.

## TL;DR

I am not looking for a workaround solution, as there are plenty of options I have already worked out.  I am simply curious if anyone knows exactly how VBA deals with these sorts of calls (not even just specific to the `ScreenUpdating` property but other Application properties as well)

Comment: best common guess is the word `application` , refering to the whole application, no ? so it does not matter wich subroutine hase the scope because you are calling an application-wide method, wich applies to ALL workbooks, all Sub or parent routines....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Application.ScreenUpdating` is a setting of the application and is activated/deactivated globally on setting and unsetting.

Your presumption is correct in that if you set it False in a subroutine, then that routine calls `BackupData` which sets it false again then sets it True before returning scope to the caller, `ScreenUpdating` is then True for the remainder of the calling subroutine.

Think of it as a variable with Global scope; wherever it is set, that value is set globally.  It's set globally for the `Application` level, which is the parent object to all workbooks open in the instance of the program (in this case `excel.exe`).  Setting it affects all workbooks in the instance; but if you have another `excel.exe` process running, it will not affect workbooks in that instance.

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  Thinking of it as having Global scope is a good way to look at it.  Will mark this solution correct when SO allows it

Comment: it's more than a global variable, because it affects other workbooks too, wich a global variable wouldn't.

Comment: Agreed - as I was trying to explain (maybe not clearly enough?), it's a global setting of the `Application` which is a parent to the `Workbooks` object.  So it applies to all workbooks opened within that instance of `Excel.exe`.  If you have a second `Excel.exe` instance open, setting in one will not impact the setting in the other one...

Answer (score 2):

this is simple use something like this. It will simple save previous state of screen updating, than it will set screenupdating to false and when you wana to set screenupdating back, it will recover it from backup. So if you already had screen updating as FALSE it will be false after.

```
Dim previousScreenUpdating as boolean
previousScreenUpdating = application.screenUpdating

application.screenUpdating = false

// your code

application.screenUpdating = previousScreenUpdating
```

Comment: If you read my question in full, you'll see that I already suggested this as a solution.  Perhaps SO isn't the right place to be asking the question, but I am looking for an answer as to the nature of VBA's default practice, not a workaround solution